# Return individual rdds from Dstream Window

Tags: spark-streaming

How to return individual rdd from dstream window ?:

```
my_dstream_window : somedstream.window(3mins,1min)
```

Suppose the above *my_dstream_window* contains {rdd1,rdd2,rdd3} I want to do some operation on

`rdd1.Operation(rdd2).Operation(rdd3)`

Intention: - *my_dstream_window* has duplicates. I could use reduceByKey to remove them for this stream but the next slice of *my_dstream_window* will have overlapping key-value pairs with older one.

So basically my task is to save distinct rdd key-value pairs only by removing any overlapping key-value from previous dstream.

Pls suggest.

Comment: my_dstream_window has duplicates. I could use reduceByKey to remove them for this stream but the next slice of my_dstream_window  will have overlapping key-value pairs with older one. So basically my task is to save only distinct rdd key-value pairs only by removing any overlapping key-value from next dstreams.

Comment: Please edit the question with the additional information in the comment.

Comment: I've answered your other question. This one is not going to help to achieve the desired outcome.

Answer (score 2):

There's a non-documented method on DStream that let's you get the RDDs belonging to a slice of time:

```
def slice(fromTime: Time, toTime: Time): Seq[RDD[T]]
```

This is used internally by the `window` functions but it's also exposed as public API. To use it, we need to keep track of time as it requires an time interval as parameter. It returns a sequence of RDDs belonging to that interval. (There were previously "remembered" either explicitly or through calling window functions)